# jquery correct way to dynamically populate elements and do callbacks specific to each one?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this in jquery. I'm GETting some data via an ajax call, and stuffing that into the page. We're dealing with a simple note taking application. Each note has its own set of data.
I've included the code that I'm woring with currently. The notes stuffed into the DOM have multiple methods(as links,) which are to do different things, e.g. save, delete, revert. When those are clicked, I want to make another ajax call and do a POST. But, how do I figure out which sticky note the save, or delete came from?

How should I handle the click events? Should I make a selector for the id of every dynamic element? That does not sound ideal, and I don't know how to do that either.
Can I have one event handler that makes an anonymous function and parses the id, where the id contains a unique identifier and a directive, such as save, delete, etc. 
Neither of these two seem like the best option. What does stackoverflow recommend?

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: 'noteGet.php',
            data: "",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(rows)
                {
                    for (var i in rows) {
                        var noteId = rows[i][0];
                        var noteContent = rows[i][2];
                        $('#allNotes')
                            .append('<span id="stickyNote'+noteId+'" class="stickyNote"><textarea id="stickyNoteTextArea'+noteId+'" class="stickyNoteTextArea">'+noteContent+'</textarea><a href="#" id="stickyNoteSave'+noteId+'">save</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="stickyNoteDelete'+noteId+'">delete</a></span>')
                    }
                }
            });


            $('#allNotes').on('click', 'a', function() {
                //what to do
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <span id="links"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply give the same `class` attribute to each element and give the action links (save,delete,etc..), their own classes so that you can identify them too.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'noteGet.php',
  data: "",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(rows){
    $.each(rows,function(index,elem)){
      var noteContent = elem[2];
      $('#allNotes').append(HTML); // see below for HTML content.
    });
  }
});

$('#allNotes .stickyNote .save_action').on('click', function(e) {
  // user clicked on a save action

  // retrieve the original id from the parents rel parameter.
  var noteId = $(this).parent().attr('rel');

  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#allNotes .stickyNote .delete_action').on('click', function(e) {
  // user clicked on a delete action

  // retrieve the original id from the parents rel parameter.
  var noteId = $(this).parent().attr('rel');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

If you want to capture them all in one main function and then decide what to do from
there, you could test for the existence of a class attribute

```
$('#allNotes .stickyNote a').on('click',function(){

  // retrieve the original id from the parents rel parameter.
  var noteId = $(this).parent().attr('rel');

  if ($(this).hasClass('save_action')){
    // user clicked on a save action
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('delete_action')){
    // user clicked on a delete action
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm going to list the actual HTML for you here separably so that it's easier to see -

```
<span rel="'+index+'" id="stickyNote'+index+'" class="stickyNote">
  <textarea id="stickyNoteTextArea'+index+'" class="stickyNoteTextArea">'+noteContent+'
  </textarea>
  <a href="#" class="save_action" id="stickyNoteSave'+index+'">save</a>
  <a href="#" class="delete_action" id="stickyNoteDelete'+index+'">delete</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must to bind event to your elements when ajax call responsed - in `ajax` `success` function.

And in the event handler you can get the element on which event fire:

```
//what to do
var element = $(this);
var noteId  = element.attr('id');
// then manipulate with it - parse or some else
```

---

Also you can store `note_id` information in attr when dynamicaly create note:

```
            .append('....<a href="#" _noteId="'+noteId+'">delete</a>....')
```

And then use this attribute:

```
// what to do
var noteId = $(this).attr('_noteId');
```

---

And if you want to have one handler for all (not good idea), you can store `action_type`:

```
            .append('....<a href="#" _noteId="'+noteId+'" _actionType="delete">delete</a>....');
```

And also use it:

```
// what to do
var el = $(this);
var noteId = el.attr('_noteId');
var actionType = el.attr('_actionType');
// then 'switch (actionType) ...'  or some else
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are adding your notes elements to the page you can place any data you want to utilize for your notes in data attributes on the notes themselves:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'noteGet.php',
 data: "",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(rows) {
   for (var i in rows) {
    var noteId = rows[i][0];
    var noteContent = rows[i][2];
    var noteEl = $('<span id="stickyNote'+noteId+'" class="stickyNote"><textarea id="stickyNoteTextArea'+noteId+'" class="stickyNoteTextArea">'+noteContent+'</textarea><a href="#" id="stickyNoteSave'+noteId+'">save</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="stickyNoteDelete'+noteId+'">delete</a></span>');
    noteEl.appendTo('#allNotes').find("a").data("id", noteId);
   }
  }
});
```

Then you can access this in your click handler:

```
$('#allNotes').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var noteId = $(e.target).data("id");
    // operate
});
```

Good luck!